# How to break a word into characters in swift

Tags: swift, func

How can i do the same thing in swift 2 :

```
String a = "danial";
  for (int i= 0 ; i < a.length() ; i++) {
    System.out.println(a.charAt(i));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
let myString = "danial"
let characters = Array(myString.characters)
print(characters) //OP : ["d","a","n","i","a","l"]
print(characters[0]) //OP : ["d"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

It was initial created.

```
let string : String = "danial"
let characters = Array(string)
println(characters)
//["d","a","n","i","a","l"]
```

String conforms to the `SequenceType` protocol, and its sequence generator enumerates the characters.

**Swift 2**, String does no longer conform to `SequenceType`, but the characters property provides a sequence of the Unicode characters:

```
let string = "danial"
let characters = Array(string.characters)
print(characters)
//["d","a","n","i","a","l"]
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Swift 4.*,

```
let stringArray = Array(wordString)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Let a = array("danial")  // a = ["d", "a", "n", "i", "a", "l"]
```

i.e. array of Character